# Getting multiple values based on a unknown condition

Tags: c#, xpath

I have following scenarion. I have a given XML structure and in there, there is a XML block defined as like this:

```
                <CHARACTERISTICS>
                    <CHARACTERISTIC id="BLOCK1">
                        <CODE>H318</CODE>
                        <FILENAME/>
                        <TEXT>VALUE1</TEXT>
                    </CHARACTERISTIC>
                    <CHARACTERISTIC id="BLOCK1">
                        <CODE>H318</CODE>
                        <FILENAME/>
                        <TEXT>VALUE2</TEXT>
                    </CHARACTERISTIC>
                    <CHARACTERISTIC id="BLOCK1">
                        <CODE>PZ123</CODE>
                        <FILENAME/>
                        <TEXT>VALUE3</TEXT>
                    </CHARACTERISTIC>
                    
                </CHARACTERISTICS>
```

Is there any way to have an outcome like this:

- Value Entry1: H318
- Value Entry2: VALUE1 VALUE2

?

So what I try to achieve is, giving on the code to get every TEXT entry based on an unknown CODE. Is that possible with XPATH?

Comment: The answer is Yea, it is possible, but what did you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Luuk our customer is sending us multiple CHARACERISTIC blocks where we have a code and a text. Each CHARACTERISTIC block is possible to have the same code and there I need every TEXT Element based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

A, very simple, example:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("CHARACTERISTICS.xml");

foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants("CHARACTERISTIC"))
{
    var Code = item.Elements("CODE").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    var Text = item.Elements("TEXT").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"{Code},{Text}");
}
```

This will output (with given example input):

```
H318,VALUE1
H318,VALUE2
PZ123,VALUE3
```

or:

```
using System.Xml; 

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("CHARACTERISTICS.xml");

foreach (XmlNode item in xml.SelectNodes("//CODE"))
{
    XmlNode text = item.SelectSingleNode("../TEXT");
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.InnerText},{text.InnerText}");
}
```